# PyGTK: Allow usage of Tab in AccelGroup

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

When using gtk.AccelGroup any combination with Tab charater is invalid. Now I do understand that UI navigation is done using this key but in some special cases I need to override that behavior. Is there a way to make AccelGroup allow usage of this key?

For example:

```
group = gtk.AccelGroup()
group.connect(gtk.gdk.keyval_from_name('Tab'), gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK, 0, callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get key names and values with this :

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import gtk
 import gtk

 def catch_button(window, event, label):
    keyval = event.keyval
    name = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(keyval)
    mod = gtk.accelerator_get_label(keyval, event.state)
    label.set_markup('<span size="xx-large">%s\n%d</span>'% (mod, keyval)) 


 window = gtk.Window()
 window.set_size_request(640,480)
 label = gtk.Label()
 label.set_use_markup(True)
 window.connect('key-press-event',catch_button, label)
 window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
 window.add(label)
 window.show_all()

 gtk.main()
```

But I found that the keynames returned were locale-dependent, of no great use for me. The keyval can probably be used.
Cheers,
Louis

Comment: And this captured Tab character?

Comment: Yeah but the issue was to connect a key combination with Tab to a specific method without resorting to listening for every key press.

Comment: Yes MeanEYE. Just run that code above to find out the key value to put in your code.

Comment: It does work but that's not the way I'd like to handle keys in my program. If at all possible I'd like for AccelGroup to accept Tab character.

Answer (score 1):

This below is one way to do it.  Although if you don't wish for the program to listen for every keypress as you stated above, I should say that I've never run across a way of tying Tab to an AccelGroup.  I've tried various things myself, but to no avail.

```
widget.connect("key-press-event",self.on_key_pressed)

def on_key_pressed(self,widget,event,*args):
    if event.keyval == gtk.keysyms.Tab:
      do_something()
```

Comment: Thought as much. I didn't know about gtk.keysyms. Thanks. I found out that when playing with CellRendererAccel you can specify that you don't want GTK parsing of shortcuts and then Tab, Arrows and other reserved keys work. I thought there might an option to do that in AccelGroup as well.